# How make <li> elements of dropdown overflow left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using `bootstrap` I'd like to show `combobox` which should expand and show its items into visible part of web page.

Given following snippet:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-5">I contain long label</div>
  <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-default btn-block dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span>Options</span>
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">This is very long text which normally overlays box on right</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/hku8a8nf/)

When `dropdown button` is `expanded` it overflows on right side and causes `scrollbar` to show.
How it would be possible to utilize free space on left side - e.g. make `<ul>` and `<li>` overflow original combobox header on other side and so prevent `scrollbar` to appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add class dropdown-menu-right to your ul item like

```
<ul id="migratorAvailableBuildings" class="dropdown-menu
migratorDropDownRight dropdown-menu-right"
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hku8a8nf/4)**

Comment: Thanks, that solved my issue. I've removed my styles which I forgot to remove from snippet as it doesn't make any role there.

Answer (score 1):

adding `.pull-right` to `ul.dropdown-menu` should do it, updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hku8a8nf/3/

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Glad to know exact property which modifies that behavior.